# Does Windows 7 Explorer support Multi-line Text for custom column?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, windows-explorer, shell-extensions

I've implemented a custom property handler for windows explorer using .NET 4.0. Everything is working except columns with multiple values is shown on the same line separated by ";". 
I've tried to set the drawControl's control attribute to Default, MultiLineText, and MultiValueText, but still no luck. What I want to achieve is to have each value on a separate line instead of separated by ";".

Here is the propertyDescription of the propdesc file that I registered:

```
<propertyDescription name="Test.Property" formatID="{A5D0A4B0-EC4D-43DA-86F6-55448D9E9430}" propID="555">
  <description>Description</description>
  <searchInfo inInvertedIndex="True" isColumn="True" columnIndexType="OnDisk"/>
  <typeInfo type="Any" multipleValues="True" isViewable="True" isQueryable="True" isInnate="False"/>
  <labelInfo label="Test Property"/>
  <displayInfo displayType="String" mnemonics="testproperty">
    <drawControl control="MultiLineText" />
  </displayInfo>
</propertyDescription>
```

Here is the implementation of the GetValue method of the IPropertyStore interface:

```
[DllImport("propsys.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern void InitPropVariantFromStringVector([In, Out] string[] prgsz, uint cElems, out PropVariant ppropvar);

public int GetValue(ref PropertyKey key, out PropVariant pv)
{

    pv = new PropVariant();
    pv.variantType = (short)(VarEnum.VT_VECTOR | VarEnum.VT_LPWSTR);
    string[] stringArray = new string[] { "Test1", "Test2" };
    InitPropVariantFromStringVector(stringArray, (uint)stringArray.Length, out pv);
    return HR_OK;
}
```